# Uniform bound of almost periodic functions

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, almost-periodic-functions

I am wondering if the following result may be true : consider a trigonometric polynomial of "almost periodic" type :
$$    f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n c_k e^{i\lambda_k x}    ,\qquad x\in \mathbb{R}$$
We moreover assume that the frequencies $\lambda_k$ are real and spaced as follows
$$  \lambda_0\geq 0  \qquad \mbox{and}\qquad \lambda_{k+1}-\lambda_k\geq 1    $$
My question is : does there exist a positive number $T>0$ (a sort of period) and a constant $C>0$ (independent of $f,n$ and the sequence $(\lambda_k)$) such that
$$     \sup\limits_{x\in \mathbb{R}}|f(x)|\leq C \sup\limits_{|x|\leq T} |f(x)|       $$
Such a question comes from the obvious fact that the answer is positive if each $\lambda_k$ belongs to $a\mathbb{Z}$ for a same $a>0$.

Thanks for having read!

Comment: For instance,  if $f$ is periodic, say $\lambda_n\in \mathbb{Z}$ then we have $ \sup\limits_{x\in \mathbb{R}}|f(x)|=\sup\limits_{|x|\leq \pi} |f(x)|$. Hence $C=1$ is convenient.

Comment: For Saulspatz, your argument does not work in the periodic case. The bound $|f(x)|\leq \sum_{k=1}^n |c_k|$ is true, but it is impossible to bound $\sum_{k=1}^n |c_k|$ by $\sup\limits_{|x|\leq T} |f(x)|$.

Comment: Your C depend on f...

Comment: If we assume that $C=1$, then this is not valid for example the function $f(x)=\sin (x)+\sin (\sqrt 2 x) $ has a supremum equals $2$ but reachs its supremum at infinity.